# Dart abstract primitives implementation

Tags: dart, primitive-types

I was looking around the implementation of basic dart types (double, int, String etc..), I found that many of these classes are `abstract`. I'm wondering if these classes are `abstract` then which class implements them? How is an object assigned to a specific type when these classes cannot even be instantiated? For example,

`double` being an `abstract` class I cannot instantiate it like

```
var d = double();
```

But then how does

```
var d = 2.5;
print(d is double);
```

prints `true`? How does dart knows that `d` is an object of `double`?

Comment: The compiler constructs `int` and `double` objects internally from `int` or `double` literals. (Hence why they're "primitives".) From there, they're generated from the results of other arithmetic operations or explicit `.toInt()` or `.toDouble()` conversions.  Constructing them via `int()` or `double()` doesn't make much sense; what value would it have?  What would happen if you tried to add them to other numbers?

Comment: well i am not looking to create primitives using constructors, just trying to understand how does it work when there actually isn't any...

Comment: You are confusing the user-level interface (i.e., the API for Dart programs) with the language *implementation*.  The language implementation need not use the same interface; the implementation could be written in an entirely different language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dart platform libraries are split into the public, shared code that you are looking at, and internal, platform-dependent code ("patch files") which provide implementations for functions that are declared `external`, and which also supply the other internal machinery that the platform depends on (and then there is also the native guts of the run-time system).

Those platform specific files contain declarations of classes which implement types like `int` and `String`. The specification says that you cannot subclass `int` and `String`, but the runtime system does so anyway. Your "primitive" objects are instances of those hidden sub-classes of the abstract interface.

The run-time system can (and does) then optimize the *representation* of some of those classes even more. For example, the VM has a subtype of `int` called `Smi` ("small integer") which stores the value in the pointer instead of allocating an object in the heap, and the web platforms implement `int` as a plain JavaScript number. They have to treat those values specially when you call methods on them, because they are not structured the same as other objects. But that's an optimization, you can think of the values as just being implemented by internal hidden classes.