# How to get the implementations of dart abstract classes in dart-lang github repo?

Tags: flutter, dart

Since dart is an open source language I was trying to get the implementations of dart abstract classes? for example I would like to see how dart team implemented String abstract class to see "trim()" method implementation, there is similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64017367/dart-abstract-primitives-implementation) maybe but couldn't help me.

Comment: Dart VM and native: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/stable/sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/string_patch.dart#L485 . Dart2js: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/stable/sdk/lib/_internal/js_runtime/lib/js_string.dart#L263

Comment: Thanks @julemand101 that is what I wanted, though their implementation is different from the syntax we used to in dart.

Comment: What do you mean by different? Do you mean the annotations used for some of the methods?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigating the Dart SDK repository require some experience before it gets easier. One reason is that it contains different implementation of some methods depending on the target platform (native vs JavaScript). Also, sometimes the native implementation is being done in C++ depending on if that makes more sense.

In your case, I have found the following two implementation of `String.trim()`. The first is used for native (Dart VM and AOT):

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/1278bd5adb6a857580f137e47bc521976222f7b9/sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/string_patch.dart#L485

And the second is used when the target is JavaScript (sometimes, we can proxy methods directly to native JavaScript methods but in this case, the `trim()` in JS does have a different behavior from the `String.trim()` in Dart. This is documented above the method in the link):

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/1278bd5adb6a857580f137e47bc521976222f7b9/sdk/lib/_internal/js_runtime/lib/js_string.dart#L263

**Note about the annotations used in the first link**

The internal Dart source code can often look a bit alien compared to the normal Dart code. E.g.:

```
  @pragma("vm:recognized", "asm-intrinsic")
  @pragma("vm:external-name", "String_charAt")
  external String operator [](int index);
```

The `@pragma` is used tell the Dart compiler some additional information. It can e.g. be to enforce inlining of certain methods. Or as here, tell the compiler it should call a C++ method bound to an entry called `String_charAt`. If we make a search in the GitHub repo. we can find that method here:

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/e995cb5f7cd67d39c1ee4bdbe95c8241db36725f/runtime/lib/string.cc#L443-L449

Comment: That is what I wanted, thanks for your useful explanation.I will explore them for more and I hope other flutter dev friends will benefit from this.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. It's quite useful for anyone wondering about the implementations like me. Cheers!